# Edit OAuth 2.0 Client IDs page not giving the option to add redirect URLs

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

Per the documentation, and many examples and answers I found, I should be able to go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials, click on my OAuth 2.0 Client ID, and have an option on the subsequent page to add redirect urls.

However, when I edit a Client ID, I am only given the name, Client ID, Client Secret and the creation date.

There are no fields nor buttons to add redirect URLs. What am I doing wrong? Where should I go to add redirect URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only web clients have redirect uris so make sure you click web client. It sounds to me like you have created a desktop client. Which does not have a redirect uri.

[image]

[How to create Google Oauth2 web application credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU)

Comment: I, somehow, had not seen the "Web client" option when I created the key.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit redirect URI for my client when I use the URL you provided. I had to use the correct Google email that matched my organisation to be able to see and edit my clients. Is it possible that your Google user id does not have sufficient permissions to edit?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of OAuth client ID you have configured? Redirect URIs can only be added for web clients. Read more about types of OAuth clients here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#zippy=%2Cweb-applications.